# how to avoid duplicate Push Notification

Tags: push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, angularfire

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-messaging.js')
firebase.initializeApp({...config});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {

console.log('sw-fb', payload);
const notificationTitle =  payload.notification.title;
const notificationOptions = {
      body:"something Body",
      data:{...}
 };
return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
},
```

Here i am  trying to show **push notification from firebase**, but for every single notification getting **two notifications**. 1st one is the default one and 2nd one is from my service worker.

can anyone help me to fix the duplicate default notification.

Answer (score 1):

to avoid default notification ,when sending through fcm need to send notification data as below

```
 var payload = {
  notification:{},
  data: {
    title:'title',
    body:'something body',
    image:path,
    icon...},
  token: registrationToken
 };
messaging.send(payload).then((result) => {console.log(result)})
```

and update srviceworker as

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
 const { data }= payload;
 const notificationTitle = data?.title;
 const notificationOptions = 
   { image:data.image, title:data.title, body: data.body, icon:data.icon }
 self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```